# Is it dangerous to increase too much Heap & PermGen Sizes inside application runing under tomcat?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, heap-memory

I have a medium web app application running on Tomcat 7.

I increased the Heap Size to -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m (via setEnv.sh of Tomcat 7) to resolve HeapSize Error.
I was wondering if it was too high values.

Does it traduces something really wrong in the code ? Or could I go further ? Is there some limitations ? What are the consequences of too big increase ?

If it's not a good solution, how could I track the error inside Eclipse. The error occurs when I launch the web app and I navigate throught it. I don't see how to use the debug mode in this case.

Comment: no it's not harmful. Your system will automatically put a cap on how much resource you can use anyway.

Comment: I have not had any issues with increasing the Heap Size... I also haven't gone over 2048 with it though. However increasing PermGen I did have weird issues after going above 2048... I recommend PermGen to be only 1024, from my understanding it is only used during deployment and undeployment, after many redeployments without a server restart you will run out of PerGen memory... A restart of the server shouldn't be a problem since you shouldn't be regularly deploying to production.

Comment: Agreed with Mohammad. The JVM default memory settings are insufficient for any web application that does any "real work".  You can also use jvisualvm as a starting point to help diagnose any suspected memory issues you may encounter wit your 2GB heap.  The value may grow depending on mamy factors (number of users, application complexity, etc.)